# Parsing in order with rangeOfString:

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

The issue I have is that I want to parse strings in order, so for instance, parsing "one three two", adding that to another string, and printing "one three two".  I'm using `rangeOfString:`, but when I parse that string, it returns "one two three".  I know that the order of parsing in my case is the placement of the `if` statements, but how do I parse that string in order? Here is my code:

```
NSString *string = @"one three two";
NSString *newString;

if ([string rangeOfString:@"one"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"one"];
}
if ([string rangeOfString:@"two"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"two"];
}
if ([string rangeOfString:@"three"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"three"];
}

NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem... Doesn't your code print the string you want?

Comment: No, my problem is that I have a string, "one three two", and I try parsing that string an putting it in to a new string and printing that, and it prints "one two three".

Comment: Your intentions are opaque. Please describe what you are trying to achieve aside from concatenating one string from the parts of another one. What is the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this wrong, you should use `componentsSeparatedByString:` and sorting:

```
NSString *stringWithNumbersOrdered(NSString *input)
{
    static NSArray *numberStrings = nil;

    if (!numberStrings)
    {
        numberStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zero", @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six", @"seven", @"eight", @"nine", /* etc. */ nil];
    }

    NSArray *components = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSArray *componentsSorted = [components sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        int value1 = [numberStrings indexOfObject:obj1];
        int value2 = [numberStrings indexOfObject:obj2];

        return value1 - value2;
    }];

    return [componentsSorted componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
}
```